# url shortener 301 redirection understanding

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, url-shortener

We're working on a URL shortener project in PHP. We're using 301 HTTP redirection and naturally track our links visits. but there is something strange :

After we shorten a URL and go through it by a browser, only the first visit is tracked, and it seems that no other request is sent to our server and it directly goes to the destination URL.(I think this is a browser cache after one try). But :

When trying with a similar service like **bitly** , it has different treat. **some** of the same requests on the same browsers are tracked in bitly visit tracking (In fact more than one of them, and I don't understand why, I don't see any logic) while they also use 301 redirection.(at left bottom of browser window sometimes writes "waiting for bit.ly..." and sometimes not , in fact randomly).

Are any tricks included here? What this different treat happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the [HTTP specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).  A `301` response tells the browser that the requested resource has permanantly moved to the new URL that is being redirected to, and should not use the original URL anymore:

> 10.3.2 301 Moved Permanently
>
> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and
>   any    future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the
>   returned    URIs.  Clients with link editing capabilities ought to
>   automatically    re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more
>   of the new    references returned by the server, where possible. This
>   response is    cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The new permanent URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the 
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to
>   the new URI(s).
>
> If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other
>   than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.
>
> ```
>   Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after
>   receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents
>   will erroneously change it into a GET request.
> ```

For what you are attempting, try using `302`, `303`, or `307` instead.

> 10.3.3 302 Found
>
> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD 
>   continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.  This response
>   is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header
>   field.
>
> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to
>   the new URI(s).
>
> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other
>   than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.
>
> ```
>   Note: RFC 1945 and RFC 2068 specify that the client is not allowed
>   to change the method on the redirected request.  However, most
>   existing user agent implementations treat 302 as if it were a 303
>   response, performing a GET on the Location field-value regardless
>   of the original request method. The status codes 303 and 307 have
>   been added for servers that wish to make unambiguously clear which
>   kind of reaction is expected of the client.
> ```

.

> 10.3.4 303 See Other
>
> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and 
>   SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method
>   exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to
>   redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a
>   substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303
>   response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
>   (redirected) request might be cacheable.
>
> The different URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to
>   the new URI(s).
>
> ```
>   Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303
>   status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the
>   302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react
>   to a 302 response as described here for 303.
> ```

.

> 10.3.8 307 Temporary Redirect
>
> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection MAY be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.  This response
>   is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header
>   field.
>
> The temporary URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to
>   the new URI(s) , since many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not
>   understand the 307 status. Therefore, the note SHOULD contain the
>   information necessary for a user to repeat the original request on
>   the new URI.
>
> If the 307 status code is received in response to a request other
>   than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Comment: well I said in my question that bitly also uses 301 redirection. but sometimes the similar request is sent to its server and is tracked. what about this?

Comment: I know what is a 301 redirection. I don't understand the reason of bitly treatment...

Comment: What's different in your `301` headers vs bitly's `301` headers?

Comment: Well this is also my question! because of this I'm confused. but you can try it. you can see that repetitive and similar visits are sometimes tracked in bitly...

Comment: Well, you know what headers you are sending.  Any decent sniffer, like Wireshark or Fiddler, can show you what bitly's headers look like. Compare the two sets and see what is different.

Answer (score 5):

Just to note down my comments..

Cache control headers also plays a role on this. If you check with curl or firebug persistant tracking, you can see the cache control headers before the location. bitly is configured to be contacted back if user clicks on the links after 90 seconds.

Comment: That's a valuable answer. Because bitly uses 301.
```    HTTP/2 301
    server: nginx
    date: Thu, 03 Sep 2020 08:28:06 GMT
    content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    content-length: 322
    cache-control: private, max-age=90
    content-security-policy: referrer always;
```